# Matrix Multiplication $C\cdot (S\otimes S)$ where one product-and is a tensor square?

Tags: matrix-product

Let $D\in\mathbb{Z}^{1\times m}$.
Let $A, A'\in\mathbb{Z}^{\sqrt{m}\times n}$, so $A\otimes A'\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n^2}$.
Let $S\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times 1}$.
I am in a regime where $m \gg n$.
I am interested in efficiently computing the product

$$D\cdot (A\otimes A')\cdot (S\otimes S).$$

This is part of some larger algorithm where $D, A, A'$ are fixed, but $S$ varies often.
So pre-computing $D\cdot (A\otimes A')$ ends up being a useful optimization (you end up having to the $O(n^2)$-dimension inner-product $(D\cdot A\otimes A')\cdot (S\otimes S)$, but merging $D\cdot (AS\otimes AS)$ is not --- this is an $O(m)$-dimension inner-product,  and I am much more sensitive about $m$-dependency during computations than $n$ dependency.

Are there any improved algorithms for computing the matrix product $C\cdot (S\otimes S)$, i.e. where one of the product-ands has a tensor-product structure?
Again, I would even be interested in the setting where one must first pre-process $C$.

Comment: It is likely that interpreting $C$ as an $n \times n$ matrix and computing $T \leftarrow C \cdot S; \textrm{return }T \cdot S$ will be faster because there is no temporary for $S \otimes S$, but I'm not sure what actually happens in practice.